# flatlist doesn't dislays any content

Tags: react-hooks, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

Good afternoon, I'm trying to make flatlist to display a number of objects from an API but for some reason, this flatlist seems not to work as I expected it to do, Wonder if anyone can find what's the issue here.
The flatlist was working properly before I import the API, because I made a custom set of data and it showed those without any issue but after I imported API like this flatlist has stopped working.

```
  const [Accounts, setAccounts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getDataList = async () => {
      await axios
        .get(
          "API LINK" //I changed the API access link for security reasons but I can get log for response and Accounts in useState hook and it works properly!
        )
        .then((response) => {
          //console.log(response.data, "loge response");

          setAccounts(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error, "loge error");
        });
    };

    getDataList(); //we can put function out of the useEffect but you need to call one in order to run the function(getDataList) once in the code by useEffect.
  }, []);
```

Flatlist code is below:

```
      <FlatList
        style={StyleSheet.container}
        data={Accounts}
        keyExtractor={(Accounts) => Accounts?.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <>
              <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.items}>{item?.games}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.price}>
                  <Text>{item?.price}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </>
          );
        }}
      ></FlatList>
    </>
```

I tried to get a log from Accounts and it shows all of the information that it gets from API but for some reason, without any errors, flatlist doesn't display any items.

This is a sample of the API data:

```
{
"id": 115,
"sellerId": 2,
"price": 105000,
"region": "2",
"isAvailable": true,
"plus": null,
"games": "Demon's Souls Digital Deluxe Edition   PS5",
"view": 17,
"createdAt": "2021-02-26T11:17:10.000Z",
"sellers": {
"username": "ben"
}
},
{
"id": 116,
"sellerId": 3,
"price": 150000,
"region": "1",
"isAvailable": true,
"plus": true,
"games": "PES 2021,Assassin's Creed Valhalla ,WWE 2K20",
"view": 6,
"createdAt": "2021-02-26T11:17:11.000Z",
"sellers": {
"username": "moeindana"
}
```

In addition, these are the styling that currently I'm using:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: "black",
    alignItems: "center",
    maxWidth: "80%",
    paddingTop: 20,
    width: "90%",
    backgroundColor: "gray",
    marginLeft: 30,
    marginTop: 26,
    minHeight: 400,
    paddingBottom: 100,
  },
  items: {
    alignItems: "center",
    maxWidth: "80%",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
  price: {
    fontSize: 15,
    padding: 17,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: "black",
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    marginTop: 20,

    top: 300,
    position: "absolute",
  },
}
```

Comment: Your `FlatList`'s `style` prop is `StyleSheet.container`, it looks like some autocomplete shenanigan and the style is actually `undefined`. Can you check that your `FlatList` actually gets a `style` prop?

Comment: Does adding `extraData={Accounts}` help fix the issue?

Comment: Use ```item.games``` instead of ```item?.games```

Comment: @MuhammadSaquibShaikh item?.games will resolve some of the errors when the API cant answer properly it means that check if item is available then go for item.games otherwise if you just use item.game in the same circumstances app will rise an error. 
Also extraData is not necessary here due of the use cases of it.

Comment: @RonB. that actually is true changed it and now I can see an overextended box 
still no data is getting displayed.

Comment: You can check like this ```item?item.games:"default value"```

Comment: @MuhammadSaquibShaikh I appreciate for all of the efforts tried both still nothing has changed.